# dir="auto" doesn't work as expected in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css

I'm building a web app, on an input text box I add dir="auto" to autodetect the text direction and it works find both in Chrome and Firefox.

when I display that text later I use dir="auto" in the container (p, span, etc..). it works fine in Chrome but the text is always displayed LTR in Firefox. (If I change it manually to dir="rtl" it works in Firefox, but I want it to be automatic)

how can I fix this ?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firefox (Gecko) **does not support** the [HTML5 dir attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-dir-attribute) properly, which specifies the element's text directionality. This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548206) and has been marked resolved on 2012-11-26.

It will be **implemented within Firefox20** (Milestone). Firefox20 moves to BETA on Week of [2013-02-18](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases#Based_on_Gecko_20).

You can detect the client's default dir attribute by using gecko's `document.defaultView` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.defaultView)):

```
// get ltr or rtl
var dir = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement,null);
```

Comment: my app is built with AngularJS, If I add this code to the HTML, dir is null. also, it breaks Angular's compiling of templates in Firefox. (it doesn't affect Chrome at all)

Comment: So in short, I don't know your src. This should be easy to debug, if you are familar with JS. `document.defaultView` returns the window object associated with the document or null if none available.

Comment: In Firefox, `getComputedStyle` returns a `CSS2Properties` object. `.style.direction` expects a string. These do not fit together.. And, what did you want to select by using `document.firstChild`? The root element? Then use `document.documentElement` instead.